# sort without order by clause in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting

I have data of about 30-45 million rows in sql server.

It takes about an hour or more to sort this data using order by clause. Is there any way to sort without using order by clause.

Comment: Do you have an index on the field you're sorting by?

Comment: How are your table and query look like? Do you have indexes on the table?

Comment: create index on which column you want to sort and use that. That will increase speed.

Comment: Your question essentially says: "*is there any way to sort the data without sorting it*" - think about it...

Comment: **No.** In any relational database, there is no order - you only get an order if you **explicitly** define an `ORDER BY` on your `SELECT`. There is no way to get order without using `ORDER BY`.

Comment: perhaps what you really want to ask is "how do I speed up this query" in which case think about clustered or non clustered indexes

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use indexes for fields what you use for sort. This can increase speed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check your indexes. If the database takes so long to do such a simple operation, it's obviously wrong or the server is too old. This amount of information is acceptable (50,000,000 rows is not too much).

You can sort the data in external program, but it won't be as efficient as doing from the DB (after all, this was designed to do this kind of things).

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-indexes-the-basics